# ¿Es seguro retornar?

Tags: c, revisión-de-código

Por que es seguro devolver cadena2? al acabar la funcion el marco de pila no seria sobreescrito? He visto que muchos compiladores guaradan el literal "hola" en una zona de solo lectura de la memoria, es por eso que es seguro devolver cadena2 sin que el marco de pila sea sobreescrito?
un saludo y gracias de antemano

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *imprimir_cadena( char *cadena2 ) {
  return cadena2;
}


int main( ){
  char *ptr = "hola";
  char *p = imprimir_cadena( ptr );

  printf( "%s", p );

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es seguro el retorno que haces, independientemente de que el literal esté guardado en una zona de sólo lectura o no.

Para entender por qué es seguro, mira este otro caso:

```
int ejemplo(int valor)
{
   return valor;
}
```

¿Te parece peligroso este código? Obviamente no, porque estás retornando *una copia* del `valor` que hayas recibido como parámetro. Aunque la variable `valor` existe en la pila y sólo mientras la función se ejecute, el `return` evalúa la expresión `valor`, y retorna el resultado de esa expresión.

Lo mismo vale cuando la expresión es un puntero. Lo que retorna es el valor del puntero, esto es, la dirección a que apunta (que es la misma dirección a la que apuntaba `ptr` en tu ejemplo, el cual está fuera de la pila de esa función).

Answer (score 4):

En tu código tanto `p` como `ptr` apuntan hacia la misma dirección de memoria, es decir, hacia la dirección de la constante `"hola"`, de que es seguro, es seguro, ya que solo la pasas como argumento a la función, lo que no impide que su dirección cambie, ahora bien, si haces:

```
#include <string.h>

char *imprimir_cadena(char *cadena2) {
  char cad[50];
  if (cadena2)
    memcpy(cad, cadena2, strlen(cadena2));
  return cad;
}
```

Algunos compiladores se quejarán de que estas retornando una variable local, otros no *(Y los que permiten retornar, optimizan la dirección de memoria de `cad`)*, lo importante aquí es que con el método que puse arriba invocas comportamiento indefinido, pero de la forma que lo planteas, es totalmente seguro retornar el mismo puntero que se recibió como argumento.

Answer (score 3):

> Por que es seguro devolver cadena2? al acabar la funcion el marco de pila no seria sobreescrito?

`cadena2` es un puntero sí, y también es local... pero la memoria a la que apunta **no** es local, luego a la memoria apuntada por `cadena2` no le va a pasar nada una vez el programa abandone la función. Otra cosa sucedería si usamos memoria perteneciente a la propia función:

```
char* func2()
{
  char cadena2[] = "hola";
  return cadena2; // <<--- cuidado!!!
}

int main()
{
  char* ptr = func2();
  puts(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

El programa también compilará pero lo mismo no obtenemos el resultado esperado...

> He visto que muchos compiladores guaradan el literal "hola" en una zona de solo lectura de la memoria, es por eso que es seguro devolver cadena2 sin que el marco de pila sea sobreescrito?

Es seguro porque la región de memoria a la que apunta sigue siendo válida después de que el programa abandone la función.

Para que el código que te he puesto antes funcione correctamente bastaría con, por ejemplo, declarar la variable `cadena2` como estática:

```
char* func2()
{
  static char cadena2[] = "hola";
  return cadena2;
}
```

De esta forma la variable `cadena2` no *muere* con la función. Otra posibilidad pasaría por usar memoria dinámica:

```
char* func2()
{
  char* cadena2 = (char*)malloc(5*sizeof(char));
  strcpy(cadena2,"hola");
  return cadena2;
}

int main()
{
  char* ptr = func2();
  puts(ptr);
  free(ptr); // No olvidemos liberar la memoria
  return 0;
}
```

El único requisito que tenemos que cumplir, por tanto, es que la región de memoria devuelta por el puntero sea válida fuera de la función.